# 'this' changes when 'props' changes

Tags: reactjs, redux

```
class Log extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.scrollLogs = this.scrollLogs.bind(this);
        window.a = this;
    }

    componentDidUpdate(){
        console.log("componentDidUpdate this.props.logList", this.props.logList, window.a == this);
    }

    scrollLogs(e){
        console.log("this.props.logList", this.props.logList);
    }



    render(){
        return (<div className="logs">
            ...
            <div className="log-list" onScroll={this.scrollLogs}>
            {this.props.logList.map((l, i) => {
                return (
                    ...
                );
            })}
            </div>
        </div>);
    }
}


var mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
    return {
        logList: state.logs
    };
}

var mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {
    ...
}

export var LogContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Log);
```

This component has a prop `logList` which is fetched from server on page load. Its initial value is [], after few seconds it has about 80 objects in it. Its value is set using redux.

In the above code when the prop `logList` changes the `componentDidUpdate` method gets fired and the value of `this` changes, hence I'm unable to access `this.props.logList` in `scrollLogs` method, which is fired while scrolling a div.

`this.props.logList` is always empty array inside `scrollLogs`. All 80 objects get printed properly inside `componentDidUpdate` method

As you might have guessed `window.a == this` prints `false`.

How do I access `this.props.logList` inside `scrollLogs`?

Comment: Can you show how `scrollLogs` is called?

Comment: also, post your component's initialization code from JSX template. how the props are passed in, etc.

Comment: I have updated my question with more information

Comment: Why would you even care about the value of `this` in React? Incidentally, you should check `componentDidMount` and `componentWillUnmount`. If you hide the component and then show it again, it will be a different component.

Comment: I don't care about `this` but I do care about `this.props.logList` which is an empty array, because its value is an empty array during mounting phase of the component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the problem. I was using webpack "hot module replacement" feature (didn't mention this in the question as I didn't know it was important). It was reloading my react components which was mutating the value of `this` hence when I tried to access `this.props.logList`, the code inside `scrollLogs` was accessing the old `this` which didn't have the new `logList`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your component is like this:

```js
<Parent>
    <Log logList={ this.props.logList } /> 
</Parent>
```

`this.props.logList` is from your redux store. When your `logList` in store change, so does the props in your `<Log />` component and that makes it re-render. That's why the `componentDidMount` triggered, and if you trigger correctly the `scrollLogs(e)`, the value of `this.props.logList` will get change too. Try call it in `render`

```js
class Log extends React.Component{
    ...
    render() {
       this.scrollLogs()
       return <div />
    }
}
```